# In Powershell, is there a consistant way to get the downloaded filename with $webRequest

Tags: powershell

This question is not duplicate as this doesn't work

```
$FileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName((Get-RedirectedUrl "https://aka.ms/win32-x64-user-stable"))
```

For VSCode the filename can be found in `ResponseUri.Segments`

```
$url="https://aka.ms/win32-x64-user-stable"
$webRequest = [net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$uri = $webrequest.GetResponse().ResponseUri.Segments

$uri
stable/ 
431ef9da3cf88a7e164f9d33bf62695e07c6c2a9/
VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.28.0.exe
```

but for yarn segment doesn't contain the msi file:

```
$url="https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi"
$webRequest = [net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$uri = $webrequest.GetResponse().ResponseUri.Segments

$uri
49970642/ 
776b5c00-c14c-11e8-934a-d10abe0380bf
```

Browser can obviously do it.

Of maybe there is something better than webrequest ?

Comment: The redirection is the issue. I used the dupe answer to get the real path of the url you posted.  In it i can see the file name.`$uri.GetResponseHeader("Location")` = 
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v1.10.1/yarn-1.10.1.msi. You can parse that to get the file name.

Comment: Duplicate do not answer the question. FYI: second link uses `Content-Disposition` header to supply name. PowerShell automatically redirects.

Comment: @Matt the other answer doesn't work for my first case.

Comment: This is what I did to get the other url where the file is actually located `$webRequest = [net.WebRequest]::Create($url);$webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=$false;$uri = $webRequest.GetResponse();$uri.GetResponseHeader("Location")` based on that I thought the dupe target sufficed. Getting the file name after that is just a matter of `Split-path` or something similar.

Comment: @Matt It doesn't always work: it works in case of yarn not in case of vscode. In case of vscode it returns empty string.

Comment: Use `Invoke-WebRequest` with `-OutFile` and define your own filename.

Answer (score 5):

Powershell (`WebRequest`) automatically redirects if there is one or more hops.
The recommended way to get suggested file name is to use [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header (`yarnpkg.com` supports it):

```
#sometimes request is rejected due to security
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

$url="https://yarnpkg.com/latest.msi"
$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$Response = $WebRequest.GetResponse()
$dispositionHeader = $Response.Headers['Content-Disposition']
$disposition = [System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition]::new($dispositionHeader)
$Response.Dispose()

$disposition.FileName #this is suggested FileName
```